# How do i fix Corona bouncing game?

Tags: coronasdk

I'm working on a ball bouncing game. when i try to run the code the message says expected "=" near "+" line 37. I'm new to Corona so i don't know what is wrong with the code. Can you guys take a look and tell me how to fix it. thank you.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRsqr.png)

[New code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me5jy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you accidentally put a 'then' at the end of line 36, where you probably intended a 'or' to be.

Thus the interpreter thinks that the code in line 37 is a variable assignment and that needs a '='.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but after fixing that i run into another error. it says Attempt to call field 'newCirle' (a nil value), i think there is something wrong with the numbers in math.random. can you help me

Comment: your problem lies in line 11 and 12. What exactly were you tying to do here? I think you put a closing bracket ')' wrong or forgot a comma ','

Comment: so i got the circle, the floor and background showing up but the ball doesn't bounce like i want it to. i uploaded the new code above

Comment: How about calling the bounceObject function with the object that is supposed to bounce. As it seems to me you only defined the functions but do not use them.

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry i'm new to this